# How can I review a missed suggested edit as the OP?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I found in my inbox that I got suggested edits.  I tried to look at them, but I got the following message:

> This suggested edit to your post has already been handled and your action is no longer required.

I **want** to look at the rejections taken, and change them.  I am not a moderator, but I pasted the question, and I have the authority to approve or reject edits.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Screenshot please? This doesn't sound like an error - there's an informational message that reads like this, but doesn't block further action.

Comment: @Shog9 I think the "action is no longer required" means that the review has been done, thus OP couldn't take any action.

Comment: Yeah, that's the message you're *supposed to* see, @AndrewT. - I'm curious if that's appearing incorrectly here, since the last edit I see in Anynomous' inbox was approved by themself.

Comment: Can you browse the link to that suggested edit review? (Perhaps from your browser's history, or if the notification is still in the inbox, it'd be easier) From that suggested edit, you can look at the rejection reason and the markdown if you want to apply the edit by yourself.

Comment: @AndrewT., the link is: [https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17192620](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17192620)

Comment: I can't even look at the edits made.

Comment: Actually, you have *approved* the suggested edit, but you also deleted the post. If you follow the link on the title there, it will redirect to [your (currently deleted) post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969376/python-schedule-tasks).

Comment: Ok, I've undeleted my post.

Comment: It is a very useless edit though, randomly bolding some words and filling up the edit queue... The reviewer was right to reject it

Comment: I just want to see it.